# What are gapless superconductors?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-order, topological-phase

How are superconducting materials classified as gapped or gapless, also is this same as saying that a superconductor is conventional or unconventional? Could you explain how this is linked to topology or the topological order in the material?

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169964/201709

Comment: There is a discussion about it in Parks' superconductivity book vol 2

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish No that doesn't help at all. I am looking more from the perspective of how you could explain the properties just by looking at the configuration of the Fermi surface and make connections to topology.