# Can cooper pair formation take place between electrons having same spin?

Tags: superconductivity

Since they're bosons, can cooper pairs have spin values other than zero like 1?
If the electrons had the same spin, can't their spins add up as 1/2+ 1/2?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that in heavy superconductors you can indeed have total spin of 1, called triplet states.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I introduce in detail there : https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/62364/16689

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair for a broad and intuitive explanation